# How to escape double(single) quotes inside another double(single) quotes with JavaScript

Tags: javascript, escaping

I have an input field where the user can enter everything (`""`, `''`). Is there any way I can escape the quotes without previously knowing their type? I mean if the user enter `("test"test'test")` how can i store it in js variable ? Any suggestion can help me.

For example, I want this to work properly:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>

    <script>

      var myVar = "test"test'test";
      console.log(myVar.replace('\"', '\\"'));

    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: `var yourString = yourInput.value;` — that’s how I’d do it. Nothing special. How would _you_ do it?

Comment: `var myVar = "test"test'test";
    console.log(myVar);`

I want to be able to do this, where the value of myVar depends on user input.

Comment: What does this have to do with input fields, then? You can escape anything with backslashes, as always: `var myVar = "test\"test'test";`.

Comment: I can`t add backslashes, because i did not write the value of myVar myself

Comment: Quotes only need to be escaped in a string *literal*, not in something the user has typed.

Comment: @user5783530 Then please explain how exactly a user would input data and how this data gets currently passed and _where_ it even gets passed. As far as I understand the question, the very first comment should already be the obvious solution.

Comment: For example if your enter "test"test'test" I have to make it available to be  used in javascript, because now there`s Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifie. I know i can escape it with "\", but maybe it have to be with function, something like : myVar.replace(' " ', ' \" '), but it not works

Comment: @user5783530 But you don’t _actually_ have spaces around each quote, right? Also, note that `'"'` and `'\"'` get parsed to the exact same thing. What you might want is `'\\"'` which escapes the backslash itself.

Comment: But I’m still not sure how exactly you use the string in JavaScript. There’s no normal way you would get a syntax error due to varying user input. If you have code that doesn’t work, _[edit] your question and provide that code_!

Comment: For example how can i make this work properly 
var myVar = "test"test'test";
console.log(myVar.replace('\"', '\\"')); , without implicitly put \ before "

Comment: @Xufox added some example in question

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116990/discussion-between-user5783530-and-xufox).

Comment: @Xufox I meant JSON.stringify() which will escape the quotes

Comment: `var myVar = "test"test'test"`. This would be broken JavaScript. You can't write that and then do a replace on it. The syntax is broken already. You need to either correct that variable declaration to make it valid via backslashes, etc, or take the input from a field given by the user, in which case you don't have to worry about it. You should never have a line like the one above in your code. Never. Because it's not valid syntax. You MUST escape it. It doesn't matter that you didn't write that value yourself. You need to fix THAT value, not try to replace something that's already broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**INCORRECT (with comments explaining why):**

You cannot do a replace on an already syntactically broken variable declaration. You need to fix the broken syntax.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
        // <-- You CANNOT do this. It's incorrect syntax. You need to escape it appropriately using backslashes.
        var myVar = "test"test'test";

        // This line is not required. You need to correct the syntax error above instead.
        console.log(myVar.replace('\"', '\\"'));
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```

**CORRECTED:**

Here you can see the correctly escaped values inside the string literal.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <body>
    <script>
        var myVar = "test\"test\'test";
        console.log(myVar);
    </script> 
  </body>
</html>
```